# Determining if function odd or even

Tags: polynomials

[This exercise](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/functions_and_graphs/analyzing_functions/e/even_and_odd_functions) on the Khan Academy requires you to determine whether the following function is odd or even

f(x) = $-5x^5 - 2x - 2x^3$

To answer the question, the instructor goes through the following process

1. what is f(-x)
2. f(-x) = $-5(-x)^5 - 2(-x) - 2(-x)^3$
3. f(-x) = $5(x)^5 +2(x) + 2(x)^3$
4. f(-x) = $-(-5x^5 - 2x - 2x^3)$
5. f(-x) = -f(x)

Therefore f(x) is odd.

Question. Why is everything converted to a negative both inside and outside the parenthesis at step 4?

At step 2, he's making x negative. At step 3, we get the result of making the x values negative. So why add the negatives again at step 4?

Comment: Note that having a minus sign does **not** make $-x$ negative. For example if $x=-1$, we have $-x=1$ which is perfectly positive.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza it is not a typo. In step 4, a double negation is applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have troubles with this approach, what you can do instead is the following:

**Step 1** Calculate $f(-x)$. This is 1.-3. in your computation.

**Step 2.** Calculate $-f(x)$. In this case

$$-f(x)=-(-5x^5 - 2x - 2x^3)=5x^5+2x+2x^3$$

**Step 3** Compare. If they are equal, the function is odd, if not, it is not odd.

[ **Step 4** Compare $f(-x)$ to $f(x)$. If they are equal, the function is even, if not, not.]

Answer (score 1):

we have $$f(-x)=-5(-x)^5-2(-x)-2(-x)^3=5x^5+2x+2x^3=-f(x)$$
since $$(-x)^5=-x^5$$
$$-x=-x$$
and $$(-x)^3=-x^3$$

Comment: it shows the derivation again..but it is not providing anymore insight to the OP.

Comment: the other answer also

Comment: I also agree. But unfortunately(fortunately depending on the changes) you were first. I will also state the same on his.

Comment: thank you but I'm looking for a simple explanation (in words hopefully) as to why all the negatives are added inside and outside the parenthesis at step 4.

Comment: both answers give a correct way to solve the problem from above

Comment: what is a simple explanation? simple in the sense of correct mathematical rules?

Comment: yes since the exponents are all even

Comment: simple like you were explaining it to a child. That's why I accepted the answer by N.S

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow the simplest process

Notice, $$f(x)=-5x^5-2x-2x^3$$ $$f(-x)=-5(-x)^5-2(-x)-2(-x)^3$$ $$ =5x^5+2x+2x^3$$ $$\implies f(x)+f(-x)=-5x^5-2x-2x^3+5x^5+2x+2x^3=0$$
Hence, $f(x)$ is odd.

Comment: this is helpful but I'm also looking for a simple explanation (in words hopefully) as to why all the negatives are added inside and outside the parenthesis at step 4. Hint, I'm not very good at math.

Answer (score 0):

In step 4, the instructor is factoring out a $-1$.

Just like $2a + 4b + 6c$ can be factored into $2(a + 2b + 3c)$, so can $5x^5 +2x + 2x^3$ be factored into $-1(-5x^5 - 2x - 2x^3)$.  He just omitted the $1$ when writing it.

The reason he factored out a $-1$ is because that makes the inner expression the same as $f(x)$, and he's attempting to prove that $f(-x) = -f(x)$.